# Visual Sorting array of images in Javascript using CSS3

Tags: css, jquery-ui-sortable, css-transitions

Check out [this demo](http://files.myopera.com/FataL/pres/pres.xml) by FaTaL. It is explained in his [blog](http://my.opera.com/FataL/blog/2009/12/07/build-web-presentation-without-flash) that he has used CSS3 `:target` and `transitions` to achieve this "visual sorting" of images. The target positions have been hard coded in pres.css

The problem is that my array of images is generated at real time. Here is a [demo](http://awishcar.com/titan/grid.php). I want to "**visually** sort" these images (on button click) alphabetically by file name. How can I achieve such functionality with CSS3 without hard coding the positions ? A JSON object of filename and other parameters will be available at runtime for the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of stuff I was looking for http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
Hope it also helps some of you out there.

Answer (score 1):

I could not think of any CSS solution. So, here is my pure Javascript solution. Live at http://jsfiddle.net/uhAEA/1/.

It sorts based on the value set on each `a` tag's `sortelm` attribute.